# SASS if function to check property value

Tags: sass

With SASS' `if()` function, is it possible to check for a property value? E.g. I want a `button` to have a `margin-right: 10px` by default. But, if the button is `float: right`, I want the margin to be `margin-left: 10px`.

Something like below:

```
margin: if(float=="right" $margin-right $margin-left);
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work (otherwise I wouldn't be writing here). But, is this possible?

Comment: You can not get the value of css properties with help of any preprocessor. But you can create mixin that will get float value and set margin.

Answer (score 0):

This mixin can set float and margin properties for any element.

```
@mixin set-button($float: null) {
  @if ($float == right) or ($float == left) {
    float: $float; 
  }

  @if ($float == right) {
    margin-left: 10px;
  } @else {
    margin-right: 10px; // default value
  }
}

.but-1 {
  @include set-button(right);
}

.but-2 {
  @include set-button();
}

.but-3 {
  @include set-button(left);
}

.but-4 {
  @include set-button(lol);
}
```

Css output:

```
.but-1 {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.but-2 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.but-3 {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.but-4 {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Sassmeister [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b42c06e39573b27ad3e94621a833b834).

Comment: You can optimize output using placeholders http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/849e8976c25219cdadf79785924837f9

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I did any css stuff so this might be LESS but you could try

```
.buttonClass {

    @if $float == "right" {

        $margin-left;
    } @else {

        $margin-right;
    }

}
```